# $(\partial_{tt}-\nabla^2+\partial_t)f=g,\quad (\partial_t-\nabla^2+b)g=\partial_t f$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, special-functions

Hi I am looking for complete solutions for $f(r,t),g(r,t)$ given in the coupled linear partial differential equations below:
$$
(\partial_{tt}-a\nabla^2+b\partial_t)f(r,t)=bg(r,t)
$$
$$
(\partial_t-c \nabla^2+b)g(r,t)=b\partial_t f(r,t)
$$
Initial and boundary conditions are given by
$$
\partial_t f(0,t)=0,\ \partial_t f(R,t)=d\cos(\omega t)
$$
$$
g(0,t)=0, \  g(R,t)=d\cos (\omega t)
$$
where $a,b,c,d,R,\omega>0.$  Note
$$
\nabla^2\equiv \frac{1}{r}\partial_r(r\partial_r)-\frac{1}{r^2}=\partial_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}\partial_r -\frac{1}{r^2}.
$$
Thank you!  Some comments:

If the right hand side of both equations are zero, (equations become homogenous), then the kernel of both linear operators are known and are in terms of Bessel functions $J_1$ (we're in a cylindrical geometry hence the Laplacian like term) times oscillating functions of time: $\sin \omega t,\cos \omega t$.

Comment: Are you interested in a solution over the segment $(0,R)\in \mathbb{R}$?  Are your boundary conditions correct?  You are using $u$ there and $g$ elsewhere.

Comment: @fred Thanks for pointing that out.  I just fixed it, the unknown functions are $f(r,t), g(r,t)$ and boundary conditions are on $f$ and $g$.  Thanks!

Comment: Over what (spatial) domain is the PDE set?  I think you only have boundary conditions and no initial conditions (in time).

Comment: @fred This is in a cylindrical basis.  The same boundary conditions would be used for the homogenous case (when the right sides of both PDEs are zero) which would yield solutions in terms of $J_1$ times oscillating functions of time.  No initial conditions on time.

Comment: So the domain is $(r,\theta,t) \in [0,R] \times [0,2\pi) \times \mathbb{R}$?  You want a solution for all $t$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29464/discussion-between-fred-and-integrals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an extension of the previous answers :

[$(\partial_{tt}+\partial_t-\nabla^2)f(r,t)=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1440553/partial-tt-partial-t-nabla2fr-t-0)

[PDE $(\partial_{tt}+a\partial_t-b\nabla^2)f(r,t)=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1438762/pde-partial-tta-partial-t-b-nabla2fr-t-0)

In the calculus below, some results which have already been obtained are re-used without more explanation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @ Integrals : Some simplifications are expected, due to the particular form of the equations : For example, probably $\mu_2=-\mu_3$ and $\mu_4=-\mu_3$ . Sorry, I cannot go further since I have no time left and I'll be away for several days. Best wishes for solving your problem.

Comment: Enjoy your time away.  Thank you very much for this! I'll go through the details and let you know if I have questions.  It seems more than sufficient.

Comment: Thanks you. Bytheway, there is a pyping mistake : it is expected that $\mu_2=-\mu_1$.

Comment: @ JJacquelin: Would you please take a look at [this problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1447956/how-to-solve-the-following-biharmonic-eigenvalue-problem) too! :)

Comment: @ H.R. : Sorry, I have not enough time to study your problem. I just took  a look. My first idea should be to look for a solution on the form of a double Fourier series (with two variables $x$ and $y$) , according to the boundary conditions, so that all boundary conditions be satisfied. Then in trying to make the coefficients of Fourier series fit to the biharmonic PDE. Hopping that it could help.

Answer (score 0):

This is sketch of how to solve your problem.  I still don't understand the boundary conditions/ initial conditions as stated.  I have set $a,b,d$ to one, and have made generic boundary conditions.

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a bounded open domain.  We are interested in solving the following coupled systems of PDE.  This is pretty hairy.

$$
\begin{align*}
0 &= (\partial_{tt} - \nabla^2 + \partial_t) f - g&\quad \mathrm{for}\  (x,t)\in \Omega \times \mathbb{R}^+ \\
0 &= (\partial_t-\nabla^2 + 1) g - \partial_t f&\quad \mathrm{for} (x,t) \in \Omega \times \mathbb{R}^+ \\
f &= 0 &\quad  \mathrm{for} (x,t)\in \Omega\times \{0\}\\ 
f_t &= 0&\quad \mathrm{for} (x,t)\in \Omega\times \{0\}\\
g &= 0& \quad \mathrm{for} (x,t)\in \Omega\times \{0\}\\
f_t &= s_1 &\quad \mathrm{for} (x,t)\in \partial\Omega \times \mathbb{R}^+\\
g &= s_2 &\quad \mathrm{for} (x,t)\in \partial\Omega \times \mathbb{R}^+
\end{align*}
$$
The fist two equations are the PDE.  The second three are initial conditions, and the last two are boundary conditions.

Step #1 Homogenize the PDE's boundary conditions.  We need to turn the boundary conditions into "forcing terms"

Let $f_{bc}$ be the solution to the following PDE

\begin{align*}
-\nabla^2 f_{bc} &= 0 &\quad \mathrm{for} (x,t)\in \Omega \times \mathbb{R}^+\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} f_{bc} &= s_1 & \quad \mathrm{for} (x,t)\in \partial\Omega\times \mathbb{R}^+
\end{align*}

With simple boundary conditions and simple geometry this $f_{bc}$ might just be a constant in space and vary in time.

Let $g_{bc}$ be the solution of a similar PDE

\begin{align*}
-\nabla^2 g_{bc} &= 0&\quad \mathrm{for} (x,t)\in \Omega \times \mathbb{R}^+\\
g_{bc} &= s_2& \quad \mathrm{for} (x,t)\in \partial\Omega \times \mathbb{R}^+.
\end{align*}

Now we have a set of new PDE's.

$$
\begin{align*}
-(\partial_{tt} + \partial_t )f_{bc} + g_{bc}&= (\partial_{tt} - \nabla^2 + \partial_t) (f-f_{bc}) -(g-g_{bc})&\quad \mathrm{for}\  (x,t)\in \Omega \times \mathbb{R}^+ \\
-(\partial_t +1 )g_{bc} + (f_{bc})_t&= (\partial_t-\nabla^2 + 1) (g-g_{bc}) - \partial_t (f-f_{bc})&\quad \mathrm{for} (x,t) \in \Omega \times \mathbb{R}^+ \\
f-f_{bc} &= -f_{bc} &\quad  \mathrm{for} (x,t)\in \Omega\times \{0\}\\ 
f_t-(f_{bc})_t &= -(f_{bc})_t&\quad \mathrm{for} (x,t)\in \Omega\times \{0\}\\ 
g-g_{bc} &= -g_{bc}& \quad \mathrm{for} (x,t)\in \Omega\times \{0\}\\
f_t-(f_{bc})_t &= 0 &\quad \mathrm{for} (x,t)\in \partial\Omega \times \mathbb{R}^+\\
g-g_{bc} &= 0 &\quad \mathrm{for} (x,t)\in \partial\Omega \times \mathbb{R}^+
\end{align*}
$$

Notice what we have done, we have changed a PDE with with inhomogeneous boundary conditions and no "forcing functions" into one with homogeneous boundary conditions with forcing functions.

Step #2.

Denote $\{\Phi_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ as a sequence of eigenfunctions for the associated homogeneous Poisson equation, ordered by increasing eigenvalue.  We mean to say that $\int_{\Omega} \Phi_i \Phi_j \mathrm{d} x = \delta_{i,j}$ and $\int_{\Omega} (\nabla \Phi_i) \cdot (\nabla \Phi_j) \mathrm{d}x = \delta_{i,j} \lambda_i^2$.  (For the cylindrical case we have $\Phi_i$ are the Bessel functions.)

Now, these eigenfunctions are complete so we can expand $(f-f_{bc})$ as

$$
(f-f_{bc})(x,t) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \tilde{f}_i(t) \Phi_i(x)
$$

and $$(g-g_bc)(x,t) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \tilde{g}_i(t) \Phi_i(x)$$

Now multiplying the PDE by $\Phi_j$ integrating by parts the Laplacian term we get
$$
\underbrace{\int_{\Omega} \Phi_i ((-\partial_{tt} - \partial_t )f_{bc} + g_{bc} )\, \mathrm{d} x}_{\alpha_i(t)} = (\tilde{f}_i)_{tt} + (\tilde{f}_i)_t + \lambda_i^2 \tilde{f}_i - \tilde{g}_i
$$

and
$$
\underbrace{\int_{\Omega} \Phi_i ((-\partial_t+1) g_{bc} +  \partial_t f_{bc})\mathrm{d}x }_{\beta_i(t)} = (\tilde{g}_i)_t+\lambda_i^2 \tilde{g}_i + \tilde{g}_i - (\tilde{f}_i)_t
$$

The beauty is that, at this point $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ are all known, and  $\tilde{f}_i$ only couples with $\tilde{g}_i$.

Step #3.  Solve ODE.

We write a state-space representation of the ODE's.
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}\left\lbrack
\begin{array}{c}
\tilde{f}_i\\
(\tilde{f}_i)_t\\
\tilde{g}_i 
\end{array}\right\rbrack + \left\lbrack
\begin{array}{ccc}
0&-1&0\\
\lambda_i^2& 1& -1\\
0& -1 & \lambda_i^2+1
\end{array}
\right\rbrack
\left\lbrack
\begin{array}{c}
\tilde{f}_i\\
(\tilde{f}_i)_t\\
\tilde{g}_i
\end{array}
\right\rbrack
= \left\lbrack
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
\alpha_i\\
\beta_i\\
\end{array}
\right\rbrack
\end{align*}
$$

Solve this system how ever you want.  This solves $f-f_{bc}$ and $g-g_{bc}$ so to get $f$ and $g$ you just add the boundary functions.  Do you see how to handle the initial conditions?  I can explain any steps that I skipped or ones that are unclear.

Comment: Thanks, although I'm not sure how useful this is.  I am not familiar with some of the notation as well.

Also
$
\int_{\Omega} \Phi_i \Phi_j dx = \delta_{i,j}
$
is not correct IF applied to the Bessel functions (Bessel functions don't satisfy this orthogonality condition if $\Phi$ is a Bessel function).  Bessel functions are orthogonal only if multiplied by a weight function (which is x).  This can be seen as a property of the Sturm Liouville operators.

Comment: Also, what is $s_1,s-2$, they should be clearly defined.  Also, for step 3, how would you solve your system? Thanks.

Comment: A few comments.  1) the missing $x$ term will appear as the Jacobian change of coordinates.  2).  $s_1$ and $s_2$ are in your case both $d \cos(\omega t)$  I am a still a little uneasy about this because It seems that boundary conditions are applied in the interior of the domain.

Comment: 3)  You can solve the ODE by methods that are outlined in Boyce and Deprima (Differential equations text) in a chapter called "Systems of first order linear differential equations).  I think that most intro Diff. Eq. texts will have a chapter on that.  I am happy to help you understand any weird notation.  I hope this helps.